# EnumDropDownListFor not selecting value, despite value being passed to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

Fairy routine situation, I need to allow users to select a value from an Enum in a ASP.NET MVC application. Since I'm using MVC version 5.2, I can simply do this:

```
// Model
public MyEnum EnumVal { get; set; }

// Controller
return View(new MyModel{EnumVal = MyEnum.SomeVal});

// View
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.EnumVal)
```

And it all just magically works. I've done it enough times to take it for granted.

But I've just noticed that the value I'm passing isn't being selected as the current value of the drop down.

I can spit out the contents of the model to verify that the value is being passed correctly, but the drop down only ever has the first value selected.

Other answers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877151/50151) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855682/50151)) seem to confirm what I thought I knew: that I shouldn't need to do anything additional to get the drop down to select the value I've passed.

Am I having a brain fart? Why isn't this working?

---

**Update**

Here's a more complete listing for the controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create(string enumVal)
{
    var valueToPass = AccountsDestination.QbDUk;
    Enum.TryParse(enumVal, out valueToPass);
    return View(new QuickBooksMappingViewModel(){EnumVal = valueToPass});
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. Is there any javascript which may be causing an issue? And I assume that controller method is a GET and your not trying to change the value in a POST, or that you do not have a parameter for the `enum` in your GET method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You nailed it! It was a clash with the name of one of the get params. Renaming the parameter was all it took. (Feel free to upgrade this to an answer and I'll accept it.)

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code - the signature of the method :)

Comment: Good point. See my update. Interesting side point: my code anonymisation may well have stripped out the relevant variable names anyway, given I didn't spot the clash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that your method has a parameter `enumVal` (which has the same name as your model property). When the method executes, the `DefaultModelBinder` adds the value of the parameter to `ModelState`.

In the view the `EnumDropDownListFor()` method first checks for a match in `ModelState` (then `ViewData` and finally your model value), which it finds and attempts to set the selection option to the value in `ModelState`. For an explanation of why this is the default behavior, refer [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111).

In your case, the value of the parameter is either the value of the first option, or does not match any option value (and the first option is selected because something has to be).

Either change the name of the parameter so it is not the same as one of your model properties, or you can use `ModelState.Clear();` to remove the value from `ModelState`.